# XAMPP for Windows - Apache not starting

Tags: apache, xampp

I was trying to set up multiple websites on my computer, following this tutorial: https://delanomaloney.com/2013/07/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-xampp/

I stopped apache and then changed two files: hosts and httpd-vhosts.conf.

Here is hosts:

```
   # Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names.     Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1             localhost
127.0.0.1             www.sewing.dev
```

And httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/sewing"
ServerName sewing.dev
ServerAlias www.sewing.dev
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/sewing">
AllowOverride All
Require all Granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I saved the files and clicked to restart apache. Nothing happens. It says that it's attempting to start but doesn't actually start. I checked the error logs, but didn't see anything that I could understand.

Error log:

```
[Fri May 22 21:33:45.065111 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2136:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri May 22 21:33:46.063513 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2136:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri May 22 21:33:55.657529 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2136:tid 384] AH00455: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 22 21:33:55.657529 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2136:tid 384] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 17 2014 11:50:08
[Fri May 22 21:33:55.657529 2015] [core:notice] [pid 2136:tid 384] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri May 22 21:33:55.657529 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2136:tid 384] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3600
[Fri May 22 21:33:57.654333 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3600:tid 276] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri May 22 21:33:58.044334 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3600:tid 276] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri May 22 21:33:58.106734 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3600:tid  276] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Fri May 22 21:41:40.093670 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2136:tid 384] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Fri May 22 21:41:42.121674 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3600:tid 276] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri May 22 21:41:42.449274 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2136:tid 384] AH00430: Parent: Child process 3600 exited successfully.
```

When I comment out all of the httpd-vhosts.conf file, apache will start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close your default virtual host directive.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost> # <<< missing closing directiv!!!
```

Comment: Thank you. I added the closing directive. One more problem: my server alias doesn't work. If I enter sewing.dev, the page says "This webpage is not available."

Comment: In your host file you've added "www.sewing.dev", try that one. Or change your host file to "sewing.dev".